# A question I'd like to ask - First Aid Kit for kitchens

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask for recommendations concerning what should be included in a basic First Aid Kit for kitchens. I don't really need to know "the answer" - I have a medical background, many years of kitchen experience, and while I've got plenty of scars I've never injured myself badly enough while cooking to require medical attention. However, I think answers generated from that question could be of use. I don't want to bother if it will be closed or seriously downvoted...that just bugs me. Any advice?

Comment: Advice : if you don't have those special finger-tip bandages, you can put on one bandaid (elastoplast) in the direction of the finger, then another one around the finger to keep it from slipping too much.  (or use medical tape for the second one).   Luckily, I don't have to use this very often.

Comment: LOL Thanks for that, if I ever post the question I hope you offer that in an answer. Here, I am actually looking for advice about wording the question in such a way that it wouldn't be seen as off-topic or otherwise inappropriate.

Comment: As per SAJ14SAJ's comment on Joe's answer, I think the best way to help ensure the question does not get closed as off-topic is to specifically ask about the difference from a *regular* first-aid kit. Otherwise it could invite people to just post whatever's in the kit they bought at the drug store or whatever.

Comment: That's easy. I've got a couple of posts in the works, so I'll get to the first aid question after that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd view it like [What knives are "required" for a serious home kitchen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/184/67) ; Although it's open ended and broad, it's a perfectly legitimate question.

Since this site started up, there's been a harder push against answers that potentially have more than one answer ... it used to be you could do it if you flagged it as 'community wiki'.  Then they tried to ban them entirely.

If you ask it, and it's closed, I'll happily vote to re-open it.

Here's a potential wording:

> As there are specific risks in the kitchen, such as burns or cuts, are there specific first-aid items that I should keep on-hand in case of a cooking accident?

(although, it might also be worth asking for non-medical supplies, maybe as a separate questions ... stuff to deal with fires, oil spilled on the floor, etc.)

Also related :

- [What safety precautions should be taken when attempting to flambe at home?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/324/67)
- [How do you put out a grease fire?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3747/67)

Comment: My main issue, since many homes only have one first aid kit, is how is this different than what is required for a general home first aid kit.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ : (1) treatment for burns (not included in all first aid kits); (2) typical location & depth of cuts (as I mentioned ... nicks at the tips of fingers are typical, and although possible to handle with general band-aids, not something most people think of)